# How can I access inside given xpath result?

Tags: python-3.x, xpath, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape a web page like this

```
<html>
etc etc..
<div id='due'>
    <h2>title</h2>
    <div>
        <div class='desc'>
           sub1
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class='desc'>
           sub2
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class='desc'>
           subn
        </div>
    </div>
    <h2>title2</h2>
    <div>
        <div class='desc'>
           sub1
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class='desc'>
           sub2
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class='desc'>
           subn
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
etc etc..
</html>
```

I first tried to scrape the section:

```
box = tree.xpath('//*[@id="due"]/*')
```

then:

```
for div in box:
    print(div.tag)
```

It returns correctly every first tag of every element, but if:

```
for div in box:
    if div.tag == 'div':
        print(div.xpath('//div[@class="desc"]').text)
```

Make the same search n times from start document and not from every individual 'div'

I would expect:

```
sub1
sub2
subn
sub1
sub2
subn
```

It returns, list doesn't have ".text" property but if I print every list:

```
[sub1, sub2, subn, sub1, sub2, subn]
[sub1, sub2, subn, sub1, sub2, subn]
[sub1, sub2, subn, sub1, sub2, subn]
[sub1, sub2, subn, sub1, sub2, subn]
[sub1, sub2, subn, sub1, sub2, subn]
[sub1, sub2, subn, sub1, sub2, subn]
```

Yep you would think that I should run once the code but I need make some variations on every iteration and create data relations, so how can I fix this?

Thank you in advanced

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I didn't solve the problem using xpath, I just moved to bs4

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, to solve your problem with xpath try this:

```
import lxml.html as lh
scr = """[your html above]"""
doc = lh.fromstring(scr)
for t in doc.xpath('//div[@id="due"]//div[@class="desc"]/text()'):
    print(t.strip())
```

Output:

```
sub1
sub2
subn
sub1
sub2
subn
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is that you are filtering data before run python loop, I needed to filter inside the for loop, due if `div.tag` isn't a div I need to make other operation and link with next incoming data up to next `div.tag` that isn't div

Comment: @Onyx I'm afraid I don't understand you. It does work with the html in the question.

Comment: yep it works but as I said on main question at the end, I need to create data relations according to `div.tag` value, and you literally just deletes boxes that aren't a `<div>`, in my sample code if you iterate without statement `if div.tag == 'div':`, you get all results inside xpath list, so I wanted to take different actions according to value of `div.tag`, for example if `div.tag == 'h2':` then create another key inside an X dict, `if div.tag == 'div':` then link text inside `<div>` into a list and link the list with last key created on X dict, something like that